# subprocess.check_output shows different behaviour on different machines

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two different machines at work and they show a weird behaviour.

When using `subprocess` in a python script to trigger external processes I get on one of the machines the output of that call as expected. On the other machine I see a shell / command line popping up, in which the statement is executed, then the window closes and then the return statement is empty.

I call it like that: 
`f = subprocess.check_output(['svn.exe', '--help'])`

And on the one machine the value of f is the command line output of `svn --help` on the other machine it's empty. I have no idea what causes this and how to react on that. Does anyone have an input?

Both machines run Windows 10 and Python 2.7.

Comment: please check if the svn is in `PATH` on your second maschine. you can type `where svn` or `%path%` in the command line.

Comment: It's the same path and known on both machines. Tortoise SVN if that matter.

Comment: try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as argument, sometimes a different outputstream is used and the normal stdout-stream is empty then.

Comment: @Skandix: Same behaviour with that additional argument.

Comment: out of ideas now - pls check if there are any warning whatsoever, when executing `svn --help` in cmd or `f = subprocess.check_output(['svn.exe', '--help'])` in pythonshell

Comment: I found a difference (still no idea how this might help or not...): On the not working machine I have the Windows 10 1709 Version, and on the working on 1607.